# How to call a polymorphic function which depends on multiple Typeclasses in Kotlin/Arrow

Tags: monad-transformers, arrow-kt

I've created a function which is polymorphic in the Monad it needs to use, instead it depends on the typeclass instances that exists for this Monad. It looks like this:

```
fun <M> M.logic(...): Kind<M, String>
      where M: MonadReader<M, Dependency>,
            M: Effect<M> =
   fx.monad() {
      val dependency = ask().bind()
      val response = effect { ...using dependency here... }.bind()
      response
   }
```

I'm using the `MonadReader` to get a dependency, and I'm using `Effect`, well, for effects. Now I assumed, that all I need is to use some Monad Transformers to get to this constellation of a Monad "at the end of the world" (i.e. in `main()`). Something like `ReaderT<ForIO, Dependency, Unit>`.

However, I can't seem to create a suitable `M` (or any context) to call this method on. How can I call this method on an exact monad that has the necessary typeclass instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code snippet you're after:

```
fun <M, F> M.logic(): Kind<F, String>
  where M: MonadReader<F, String>,
        M: Async<F> =
  fx.monad {
    val dependency = ask().bind()
    val response = effect { dependency }.bind()
    response
  }

object Transformer: 
  Async<KleisliPartialOf<ForIO, String>> by ReaderT.async(IO.effect()),
  KleisliMonadReader<ForIO, String> by ReaderT.monadReader(IO.monad())
```

Note that `Async` is what you're after, not the poorly named `Effect`. And you need two generics, one for the composition and another for the content.

```
Transformer.run {
  logic()
}
```

The Async instance for Reader was added on January 2020, and will be available on the next release, either 0.10.5 or 0.11.0: https://github.com/arrow-kt/arrow/commit/6aaae6998de612eb0eec948697f1c477649230be

Comment: Thanks, I compiled the 0.10.5-SNAPSHOT and it provides the instance for the code you provided. Unfortunately both delegates of the `Transformer` now implement the basic stuff, like applicative/functor/etc. This means I would have to explicitly override those (many dozens of) methods and delegate them manually. All in all, I think it may not be worth the effort :)

Comment: Many dozens? I would have thought it was just a couple, the ones that are not default implementations.